# C++ streams in Android. How to write to the device memory using std::ofstream?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, filesystems

In order to write to a file on sdcard to add **android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** in AndroidManifest.xml. What need to add / do to keep a record of the device memory (flash / application folder)?

Write function:

```
bool write_to_file(const std::string & file_name, const std::string & text)
{
     bool res = false;

     std::ofstream stream (file_name.c_str (), std::ios::out);
     stream.clear();
     if (! stream.fail()) {
         res = true;
         stream << text.c_str() << std::endl;
     }
     else {
         LOGE ("std :: ofstream: wtire error");
     }
     stream.close();

     return res;
}
```

Call example

```
std::string file("/sdcard/text.txt");
write_to_file(file, "simple text"); // OK !!!

std::string file("./text.txt");
write_to_file(file, "simple text"); // ERROR !!!
```

Comment: question was in the text. added it to the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is passing the right file name to the native code. In Android, you use `Context.getDir()` to retrieve a data folder location in the phone memory. Like this:

```
File Path = Ctxt.getDir("Data");
File FName = new File(Path, "MyFile.txt");
```

Then pass `FName.toString()` into the native library somehow. The pasted snippet won't be directly callable from Java - the [glue code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354411/android-ndk-native-function-call-issue/11354714#11354714) is missing.

In versions of Android that I know of, the file path above would correspond to the following filesystem path: `/data/data/com.mypackage/app_Data/MyFile.txt`. But you cannot rely on that.

Writing to arbitrary paths of the device filesystem is prohibited by OS permissions. You have your sandbox, go play in it. Such is the smartphone way.